# Automation Error when trying to protect VB project and email it as attachment

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting an automation error when I try to protect a VBProject and email the workbook as attachment. What am I missing here?

Here is code to Protect VB project:

```
Sub ProtectVBProject(WB As Workbook, ByVal strPassWord As String)

Dim vbProj As Object

Set vbProj = WB.VBProject

'Is it already locked!    
If vbProj.Protection = 1 Then Exit Sub

Set Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject = vbProj

'SendKeys to set the project password    
SendKeys "+{TAB}{RIGHT}%V{+}{TAB}" & strPassWord & "{TAB}" & strPassWord & "~"

Application.VBE.CommandBars(1).FindControl(ID:=2578, recursive:=True).Execute

   'Close and Save    
    WB.Close True    

    End Sub
```

Here is code that calls ProtectVBProject to Protect VB project and attach the workbook and mail it

```
 TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
    TempFileName = "Email Test " & Sourcewb.Name & " " _
                 & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss")

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
OutApp.Session.Logon
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

With Destwb
    .SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr, _
            FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "aab2323@example.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Test Subject"               
        Call ProtectVBProject.ProtectVBProject(Destwb, "pa$$w0rd!")                
        .Attachments.Add Destwb.FullName
        .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    .Close SaveChanges:=False
    Destwb.Close SaveChanges:=False
End With

Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
```

Comment: A quick look reveals no bad coding style. Where exactly does the error occur and what (if possible) is the error type and description?

Comment: @BK201 I resolved the Automation Error, I was closing the book twice and the second .close was throwing the error.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, SendKeys (for locking/unlocking projects) is not very trustworthy and many/most people will advise against using them.

Take a look at [this blog](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2013/04/24/unprotecting-vba-project-password-using-a-password-that-you-know/) for an alternative way to accomplish what you're trying. ([This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16174469/unprotect-vbproject-from-vb-code/16176557#16176557) SO post is also helpful.)

While those links deal with unprotecting a project, I'm sure the methods can also be used to protect the project.

If you'd rather not use that route, try using a "template," where the "template" workbook already has the proper code and the project is locked. Then you just open the template, paste whatever content you need into the workbook, and then `SaveAs`. (This is the method I used [in a similar situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17777770/vba-project-password-protect-with-sendkeys-not-working-correctly).) Once saved, you can send your file via email.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the extra reference to `ProtectVBProject`.

Your code says `Call ProtectVBProject.ProtectVBProject(Destwb, "pa$$w0rd!")` yet I think it should only say `Call ProtectVBProject(Destwb, "pa$$w0rd!")`

Comment: My module is named ProtectVBProject and my sub is named ProtectVBProject. This is how to call a sub from a module. ModuleName.SubName()

Comment: Hm, even though that may work, it's really bad practice to give different things identical names...

Answer (score 0):

I Think it may be because you are trying to send the workbook while it is still open. You can do this manually without issue but when I try to do this through SMTP it fails.

I guess you only want to send (as opposed to saving) the protected workbook so your options are either save a separate copy that is protected, close it and then send the email and kill the file. Or you could save it, close, send, re-open and un-protect using similar code to how you protected.

Comment: I am not trying to send the workbook which is open, I save a temp copy and send that copy

Comment: Then that may be your problem, I don't think you can access the VBProject property without the workbook being open - you would get an automation error if you tried to. BK201 asked where the error happens, could you let us know? And also maybe post a little more of you code, the setting of DestWb and SourceWb would be the primary requirements to help further.